# Gitlab with non-standard SSH port (on VM with Iptable forwarding)

Tags: configuration, ssh, virtual-machine, iptables, gitlab

My `gitlab` is on a virtual machine on a host server. I reach the VM with a non-standard SSH port (i.e. `766`) which an iptable rule then forward from `host:766` to `vm:22`.

So when I create a new repo, the instruction to add a remote provide a mal-formed URL (as it doesn't use the `766` port. For instance, the web interface give me this:

#### Malformed

> git remote add origin git@git.domain.com:group/project.git

Instead of an URL containing `:766/` before the group.

#### Wellformed

> git remote add origin git@git.domain.com:766/group/project.git

So it time I create a repo, I have to do the modification manually, same for my collaborator. 
How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

if you configure the ssh_port correctly in config/gitlab.yml, the webpages will show the correct repo url.

```
## GitLab Shell settings
gitlab_shell:
  ...
  # If you use non-standard ssh port you need to specify it
  ssh_port: 766
```

ps. 
the correct url is:
ssh://git@git.domain.com:766/group/project.git

edit: after the change you need to clear caches, etc:

```
bundle exec rake cache:clear assets:clean assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing and I got the correct URL in `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production'` output but not in the web interface

Comment: seems there is a cache that was preventing the modification to appear in the web interface. Not sure what it is (sidekiq, gitlab)

Comment: Assumming this is a bit old I have the same issue... you claim it was due o to a "cache" the modification from appearing? Could you clarify how to fix. Thanks.

Comment: For omnibus installations this file can be found in: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml

Comment: @luison 
`bundle exec rake cache:clear assets:clean assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Just in case someone is having trouble with this and the env:info from @ÉdouardLopez is showing the correct urls, but the web interface not, you should restart apache, if you are using it. It worked for me. I guess unicorn is caching the data somehow.

Comment: Restarting the server fixed it for me (restarting nginx by itself didn't) if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 107):

In Omnibus-packaged versions you can modify that property in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 766
```

Then, you'll need to reconfigure GitLab:

```
# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Your URIs will then be correctly displayed as `ssh://git@git.domain.com:766/group/project.git` in the web interface.

Comment: You also need to make sure that ssh is told to listen on that port, otherwise the connection will be refused. By default it is /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: I had to run `gitlab-ctl restart` in addition to `reconfigure` but after that, my ssh links on the web interface were updated.

Comment: When using the official gitlab docker container, the used sshd config file where the listen port also has to be changed is: /assets/sshd_config
 
Restart sshd after editing the port using: /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Comment: If you also edit */etc/ssh/sshd_config*, don't forget to restart sshd, e.g. `service sshd restart`.

Comment: Not working in my case, i have a gitlab in ec2 in private subnet behind an ELB, when i use 766, the git cant connect

Answer (score 5):

**N.B.:** this was tested on an **old Giltab version (`v5`-`v6`)**, and might not be suitable for modern instance.

You can achieve similar behavior in a 2 step process:

### 1. Edit: `config/gitlab.yml`

On the server, set the port to the one you use:

```
ssh_port: 766
```

### 2. Edit `~/.ssh/config`

On your machine, add the following section corresponding to your gitlab:

```
Host sub.domain.com
        Port 766
```

### Limit

You will need to repeat this operation on each user's computer…

### References

- [GitLab and a non-standard SSH port](http://florentpousserot.blogspot.fr/2012/09/gitlab-and-non-standard-ssh-port.html)

Comment: @josch the answer was for an older version of Gitlab like version ~5-6

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix this issue:

```
ssh://git@my-server:4837/~/test.git
git clone -v ssh://git@my-server:4837/~/test.git
```

[Reference URL](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206161269-Git-VCS-root-configuration-with-SSH)