# Сannot access to local gitlab server via SSH

Tags: ssh, centos, gitlab, portforwarding

Looking up for some help with ssh access

I’v got a centos 7 physical server in local network of 2 computers, static ip, and remote server with project (also centos)

Installed gitlab on centos, forwarded external port 8686 to internal port 77 port on router

Everything is working now by http:

```
git remote add origin http://123.456.789.101:8686/user/project.git
```

Now I’m trying to make access via SSH

I’v generated .pub key with ssh-keygen on remote server, copied it to gitlab webinterface

Now, when I’m trying to check connection with port:

```
ssh git@123.456.789.101:8686
```

I’v got :“Name or service don’t known” error

without port or trying to add git@ remote:

```
ssh git@123.456.789.101
git remote add origin git@123.456.789.101:8686/user/project.git
```

I’v got :“Connection timed out” error

What did I miss and how should it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on [which port your GitLab is configured to listen to for SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517451/6309)

But I doubt it can be the same port as the one listened to for HTTPS.
Unless you use the [alternate SSH connection](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/) (but that is only for gitlab.com), or use some SSH tunneling, as in [issue 495](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/495).