# kex_exchange_identification while connecting to local gitlab instance

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys, openssh

I've set up a local instance of gitlab with the following configuration:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: 'gitlab.local.com'
    restart: always
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.local.com:4005'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 3005
    ports:
      - '4005:4005'
      - '3005:3005'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Then I've added SSH keys according to the gitlab documentation.

Finally when connecting to the instance via SSH or cloning a repo I get the following error:

```sh
ssh -Tvv git@gitlab.local.com -p 3005
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.local.com" port 3005
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.local.com [0.0.0.0] port 3005.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rafael/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've disable ufw, I've reset the known_hosts, I've tried everything I can think of and found nothing on the internet that helped me.

Why is this error appearing? It's the only "server" I have problems acessing via ssh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first the ssh daemon, in your GitLab Docker container, does listen to port 3005 (a [custom port](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/docker/README.md#expose-gitlab-on-different-ports)).

See for instance [`gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab` issue 1767](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/1767):

> I had to say that this issue gave me very hard time trying to figure things out.
> It is really counter-intuitive that `gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 30022` only works to change the URI displayed in the web page instead of also changing the port `sshd` serves in guest machine.
> Besides subjective feelings above, there are also two facts in the way it currently works:
>
> - There is no way to change the ssh port gitlab shell uses on the docker container.
> - When using the docker's ip address to access the gitlab server, port would always have to be 22 instead of what is used in the URI.
>
> I would argue that the way original document described is a better way how things should work around the issue.
> `gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']` should also change the port gitlab-shell is served on guest side.

And:

> You have to customize the port inside the file `/assets/sshd_config` by your Dockerfile.

That was [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26935369/6309).

Since I see "Connection established.", it is possible, since those bug reports, that `sshd_config` is now correctly modified (automatically)

If that is the case, double-check what public key you have registered to your GitLab profile: it should be  `/home/rafael/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.