# Can I change the port a GitLab runner uses to pull from my self-hosted GitLab instance?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two virtual machines both running docker. On one, I am hosting a GitLab instance according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html. On the other, I have a GitLab runner running inside a container https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html.

Due to some port constraints, I am running the GitLab instance on non-standard ports (4443 instead of 443, for instance).

I am able to successfully register the runner, and GitLab can send a job that the runner will pick up. However, when that runner pulls the git repo it is apparently looking at the wrong port for that git pull:
[image: a GitLab screenshot of a CI/CD error where a runner is pulling the wrong port]

My GitLab is on port 4443 not port 443. The GitLab runner config has the correct port in the `url` field and is, again, able to connect and receive jobs.

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
[[runners]]
  name = "runner1"
  url = "https://vm-pr01:4443/"
  token = "egZUzK44hYVrhy6DTfey"
  tls-ca-file = "/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/cert.crt"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:20.10.16"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Finally, I did try to change the GitLab ssh port according to this question:
[Gitlab with non-standard SSH port (on VM with Iptable forwarding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517189/gitlab-with-non-standard-ssh-port-on-vm-with-iptable-forwarding/18517451#18517451)
But that wasn't effective after restarting GitLab.

Are there other angles to try? My last thought was to host my own `docker` image with the correct ports changed in SSH config but I imagine there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`clone_url` configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#how-clone_url-works) for the runner to change this.

```ini
[[runners]]
# ...
clone_url = "https://hostname:port"
```

Make sure the scheme matches your instance (http or https).

For whatever reason, the default clone url will not precisely respect the setting from `url` (scheme and port are assumed) so you must provide both `url` and `clone_url` in your configuration scenario.